# SSRS how to subtract previous column value from column value in a group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

The data it is passed to my SSRS report contains total shift output value. it is separated by hour, But to show actual hour output I have to subtract from previous column value:

Current situation:

```
          07:00 08:00 09:00 10:00 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00 ...
Line 1     25    55    79    105   130   155   185   205   ...
```

Expectation:

```
          07:00 08:00 09:00 10:00 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00 ...
Line 1     25    30    24    26    25    25    30    30   ...
```

In the column value for the Group Hour I have:

```
=Fields!HourTotal.Value
```

Comment: Please show your table design in SSRS studio

Comment: The "current situation" is how my table design looks like

Comment: i mean this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/XmrJe.jpg

Comment: Don't worry mate, I done subtraction in SQL